# Create an ordered single linked list with numbers

Tags: c, linked-list

So up until now this is the code I have. I'm having problems implementing the main function because linked-lists are a new subject for me. Could someone explain me what should I include to have an output like this

The output should look like that after inserting 2, 0, 3, 5 and 4 in an, initially, empty list:

2

0 2

0 2 3

0 2 3 5

0 2 3 4 5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {

int number;
struct node *next;

} NODE;

NODE* insert(NODE *, int);
NODE* delete(NODE *, int);
void traverse(NODE *);
NODE * search(NODE *head, int data);

main(){

        list *newnode, *start = NULL; // this will point to the first node of the list


}


NODE *search(NODE *head, int data){ //search for the right position to add data

        NODE *previous=NULL;
        NODE *current=head;

        while (current !=NULL && data > current->number)
        {
                previous=current;
                current= current->next;
        }
        return previous;
}

NODE *insert(NODE *head, int data){ //allocates a new node with data value

        NODE * temp;

        if (temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)==(NODE*)NULL))
                return 1; //malloc have failed
        temp->number = data;

        NODE *previous;

        previous=search(head,data);

        //two cases 1) add at front 2)add elsewhere
        if (previous==NULL)
        {
                temp->next=head;
                head=temp;
}
        else
        {
                temp->next = previous->next;
                previous->next = temp;
        }
        return head;

}

void traverse (NODE *head){

        NODE * current = head;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
                printf(" %d ", current->number);
                current = current->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
}

NODE* delete(NODE *head, int data)
{
        NODE *previous, *temp;
        previous=search(head,data);

        if(previous==NULL && head->number==data)

        {
                temp=head;
                head=head->next;
                free(temp);
        }
        else if (previous->next !=NULL && previous->next->number==data)
        {
                temp=previous->next;
                previous->next = previous->next->next;
                free(temp);
        }

        return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void printList (list *currentPtr)
{
    if (currentPtr == NULL)
        printf("list is empty.\n\n");
    else
    {
        printf("The list is:\n");
        while (currentPtr != NULL){
           printf("%d --> ", currentPtr->number);
           currentPtr = currentPtr ->next;
        }
        printf("NULL\n\n");
    }
}

The list is: 
0 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> NULL
```

Yo can take away  the NULL and the -> if you want.